# CSS/JS to shade <td> as a bar graph?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I would like to use a `<td>` cell to visually "graph" a percent that's in the cell next to it.  I will be bringing in the percent and want to shade it like a bar for a graph.  Has anyone tried to do that and would it be easier to do it with CSS or JS function?  I am using a html/php combo on the page.

Comment: It depends..if you want interaction, use CSS changed dinamically by JS, else go for a pure CSS(3) solution. What do you mean by "shade it like a bar for a graph"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple sample of how it could be done. It's really just a matter of basic CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/e5wRA/1/

## Updating the Bar

**Javascript** (jQuery):

```
var percent = 20;

$('.bar').css({
    width: percent.toString() + '%'
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $percent; ?>%</td>
    <td class="graph"><div class="bar" style="width:<?php echo $percent; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How would I change the % width of the td cell dynamicly?  I will be calculating the % in php and delivering it to the table.

Comment: Exactly what I would propose, have the height or width (depending on the direction of the graph) reflect the percentage of the total

Answer (score 2):

In general, it’s a good idea to use CSS classes to style elements. Then use Javascript to change the class name as needed. This method allows you to separate presentation (CSS) from behavior (javascript).